# Animating moving clouds with pure CSS

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create something like the image below just with a CSS animation where the clouds are moving. [image]

I made the clouds as an SVG and created the animation. However, I am having a hard time positioning the clouds. I created ten clouds but only a couple of shows with a hard time fit different screen sizes. How should I go about creating these 10 clouds slowly moving across the screen?

Also, how should I go about creating the clouds divider at the bottom of the image above? Should I create this as an SVG background or how can I achieve this with CSS?

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds{
 background-color: #272b36!important;
}

.cloud {
 width: 400px; height: 100px;
 background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/White-cloud-type3.svg);
 position: relative; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* create all of the clouds */
.sky1 {
  opacity: 0.4;
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 45s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 45s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 45s linear infinite;
}

.sky2 {
 left: 200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
 transform: scale(0.6);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 50s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 50s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 50s linear infinite;
}

.sky3 {
 left: -250px; top: -200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 60s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 60s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 60s linear infinite;
}

.sky4 {
 left: 470px; top: -250px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
}

.sky5 {
 left: -150px; top: -150px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 55s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 55s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 55s linear infinite;
}

.sky6 {
 left: 470px; top: -270px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
}

.sky7 {
 left: 470px; top: -375px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
}

.sky8 {
 left: 470px; top: -350px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
}

.sky9 {
 left: 470px; top: -150px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
}

.sky10 {
 left: 470px; top: -450px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.4;
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 65s linear infinite;
}

/* create the animation */

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="clouds">
  <div class="cloud sky1"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky2"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky3"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky4"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky5"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky6"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky7"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky8"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky9"></div>
  <div class="cloud sky10"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `scss` syntax to loop through elements and create dynamic values for position and animation duration.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/694dwy30/)

```
$clouds: 10;
@for $i from 0 through $clouds {
  div.cloud:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
    left: random(150) / 150 * 100% + 50%;
    top: random(100) / 100 * 90%;
    transform: scale(random(2) - 0.5);
    opacity: random(60) / 100;
    animation: moveclouds random(20) + 20 + s linear infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes moveclouds {
  100% {
    left: -50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wth this is awesome

Comment: @Pete I think that can be adjusted, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/nr0h7ygx/